# User have only edit permission (not add/delete) but can still drag and drop documents and replace existing ones

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, edit, drag-and-drop

I've created a custom permission that only `allows user to edit item, and not allow user to add or delete`.

However, user is still able to `drag and drop items into the document library` and even replace existing ones when they shouldn't be able to.

Is there a way to `restrict user` from drag and drop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop users from creating new documents you can disable "New document" option by setting the Toolbar option of webpart to "No Toolbar"

To disable drag-drop use below code in script editor on same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Stop Drag & Drop 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { 
g_uploadType = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED; 
SPDragDropManager.DragDropMode = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED; }, "DragDrop.js");
</script>

<style>
#Hero-WPQ2 {
display: none ! important;
}
</style>
```

[Blog link](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/15/hide-disable-new-doc-drag-drop-files-document-library-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Although, is there a way to disable the drag and drop function to a specific group of users that have the same permission, say the visitors that have edit permission?

Comment: There is a way but I won't recommend it. If you check the code of drag-drop.js  you can override the drop function add your custom code to page